# How to print QuickFix Suggestions in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

With no help from googling, can anyone explain if it's possible to print the eclipse quickfix proposals for an error in the console and if so how to do it?

A snapshot of the proposals i want to print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghJGa.png

Comment: That's not "quick fix", thats "autocomplete" ... quickfix is clicking on the line with a mark next to it and then picking one of the options, like "wrap in a try/catch block".

Comment: Yeah the autocomplete can you explain how to print them in the console

Comment: I cannot. I'm not familiar with Eclipse plugins API but even if i were - why for the sake of heavens do you want to dump all methods of a class in the console? If you're developing a text-based IDE similar to VI, wouldn't two or three autocomplete prints completely mess up whatever you're looking at?

Try to explain the idea behind this and you might get a better, saner suggestion. For now, the best I can tell you is that you need to roll your own Eclipse plugin and that there's API for that.

Comment: Ok..let me explain ..this is a university project,,the tutor told us to try to print the suggestions that are in the image link above in the console..We got stuck..tried searching a lot but could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Your question is pretty strange....
In what manner your console should accomplish that autocomplete function?

Comment: Oh, well supposing your teacher doesn't really know what he asked you to do and he doesn't go deep in the code to realize how you faked it - i suggest using Reflection to get all methods of a certain class. So that's not mimicking autocomplete, that's actually printing all method names of a certain class. Different idea, looks the same way in the console :)

Comment: And hey - if he does inspect the code and sees reflection, i seriously doubt he will mark you down for using it and providing results he expected to see.

Comment: I removed the quickfix tag because it was incorrectly used.  Quickfix is and api for FIX the Financial Information eXchange protocol. Please try to understand the tags you are clicking and not just click them because you think they are what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just to explain why autocomplete in console is a bad idea -

boot up linux. go to a folder with lots of files. press A then tab a few times, then type in some more letters and press tab a few more times.

After fifth tab your "intent" (the thing you're trying to type and copy/paste into a file for instructions or what not) is completely lost and you might even forget what you started doing. The filename suggestions will swamp your input and break the "command flow".

Now, how to get method names in the console -

i recommend reflection. Here's something on it http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/reflection/index.html

You just need to fetch all Methods of a Class and print their names. This will look exactly like what your tutor mentioned. If he wants to see how you did it, he will see alot of code he doesn't understand and will probably say "yes yes, fine work students" and pass you.

If you're gonna be a coder you might as well learn the industry's big secret - we fake alot. Learn how to fake properly ;)

or just go here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Reflection/Accessing_Private_Features_with_Reflection and copy/paste.

EDIT:

You want this piece

```
Method methods[] = someClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethods(); 
System.out.println("Access all the methods"); 
for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) { 
   System.out.println("Method Name: " + methods[i].getName());
   System.out.println("Return type: " + methods[i].getReturnType());
}
```

Comment: Ypu are getting me completely wrong,i dont want to print the method names..suppose you type system.out.something..as soons as you press.[the suggestion list appears and i want to print the suggestions in the list in the console]

I tried your solution but this is not what i want

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Shark suggestion towards the upper class.
You should then use a proper structure to indexing everythin.